# Confirm form submit with dialog in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm learning my way around Jquery Mobile, but I'm getting stuck at confirming a form submit using the jq mobile dialog options. Wheneven I try to launch my runSearch() function from my dialog I get an "Error Loading Page" message, if I run the runSearch() function directly from srch.asp the page loads just fine. I'm working off the daily builds of of jqmobile.

Here's what I have so far:

srch.asp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Filter page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body  >
 <div data-role="page"  data-add-back-btn="true"  id="main">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="inline">    
    <title>Filter page</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    var count = 26;
    function doSearch(){
        //var sqlStr = generateSQL();
        var sqlStr = 'xxx';
        document.getElementById('sqlSrch').value = sqlStr;         
        if (count > 25){
            $("#lnkDialog").click(); 
        }
        else{           
            runSearch();
        }             
    }
    function runSearch(){
        $.mobile.changePage( "/mobile/famName/results/en", {
            type: "post", 
            data: $("form#frmSelectors").serialize()
        });        
    }
    </script>
  </div><!-- /header -->
  <div data-role="content"> 
    <form id='frmSelectors' method="post"  action="/mobile/famName/results/en">
      <input type="hidden" name="sqlSrch" id="sqlSrch" />
      <input type="hidden" name="famID" value="xxx" />
      bunch more inputs go here....
      <input type="button" value="Search" id='srch' onclick="doSearch()" style="srcButton"/>
      <a id='lnkDialog' href="#toomany.asp" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"></a> 
    </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->        
    </div><!-- /page -->      

     </body>
    </html>
```

toomany.asp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Warning</title>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Warning</h1>
  </div>    
  <div data-role="content"  data-theme="b">
    <div id="text">Error Message</div>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-transition="slidedown" data-theme="b">Yes</a>  
    <a href="#" onclick="runSearch();" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown" data-theme="c">No</a>
   </div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding return false; after runSearch();

Comment: i would recommend you look into using jquery more if your going to use jquerymobile. its great and there are some places in ur code where it would come in handy!

Comment: Adding return false; after the runSearch(); call in toomany.asp did not fix this issue, nor did adding return false to the runSearch function.

Answer (score 0):

In your srch.asp, you provide the link:

```
  <a id='lnkDialog' href="#toomany.asp" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"></a>
```

The Link to #toomany.asp would link to an anchor in the same page, but you have a real page to link to, see here for details:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/pages/page-links.html

You should use this link instead to link to the other page as dialog:

```
  <a id='lnkDialog' href="toomany.asp" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied form @Senad Meškin's comment:

try adding return false; after runSearch();

This solved the same error on the JQMobile based web app I was working on.  After the form was submitted the 'error loading page' error occurred.  Simply adding the line `return false;` to the function that was being run on submit fixed the error.  While this appears not to work for the OP others directed here by Google etc may find this helpful.